# Can someone explain this occurrence with a fbx model in xna?

Tags: xna, c#, models

Because this is kind of weird to explain, let's show you what I mean.  This is in my game.  When I import this base ship model, it should be at (1000,1000,1000), but the model acts like it's at (1000,1000, 0).  Note it is positioned correctly when I use a .x model.  So it has to be the model.  I need to know what's wrong with it.

Here is the model file, tell me if anything is wrong with it: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/92848165/station2.FBX

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVUed.jpg

EDIT: The model works if you import it into Google Sketchup...but you lose the textures, not very nice.

Comment: Is the model centered to the origin inside your modelling program? Are you applying the correct transforms to all of its bones before drawing it? (And did you post this to /r/gamedev? I think I saw a simillar screen before).

Comment: I have no idea, it looks so in the fbx file.  Take a look yourself.  I never posted anything related on r/gamedev, do you think they know?

Comment: If Google draws it properly, then there's something wrong in your source code. Are you using the default Content Pipeline to load the model?

Comment: @Marton Yes, obviously.  I figured out that it was the transformations that effected the models.  If you move them to the center, it actually doesn't matter, cause even if it looks at 0,0,0 it will be drawn at how much you moved it.  You need to Freeze Transformations and Delete Object History.

So it obviously wasn't my source  code like you said :P

Comment: Well, then whose source code was it?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is really really late....

The only solution to this that crosses the mind is that the model isn't centered in the origin....

Try making the model in a different software (importing / exporting again).... Use blender as it is free and is pretty easy to use:

http://www.blender.org/